# Move Desktop application to .NET web application - Silverlight or Telerik controls

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller, user-interface, telerik-mvc

Our client has a Desktop application (VBA and Access) that they are using for the past 10 years and it is buggy and they want to upgrade it. I want to use the latest MS technologies and plan to make this a web application using .NET 4.0, C#, SQL server and MVC running on the Intranet. 
Since the application has many visual components (about 10 different tabs on top and each tab has atleast 10 different controls on it), I was wondering what is the best way to implement the UI layer a .NET web application. The 2 candidates are Silverlight and Telerik controls (we have license for this).

Some issues to consider :

1. Silverlight Plug-in : Since this new application will only be used internally on the intranet, I dont think installing a Silverlight plug-in will be an issue. Also, since its on the intranet, hopefully download speed should not be an issue for SL apps.
2. Telerik-MVC : It is really rich in functionality, however, I played around with it (.NET version not MVC) using some of the controls and if there is anything out of the recommended way to use a control, its a pain to get it working.
3. Skill-set : Do I want to learn how to use a tool (Telerik) or would I be better off learing a technology (Silverlight) in terms of future projects.

I would like to hear any feedback/ issues to help me decide which way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you are replacing a desktop application then going with Silverlight may be the best approach.

With Silverlight you are writing an application that happens to be delivered across the internet (well intranet in this case). This can be as stateful as you need to be. You have good access (no pun intended) to the database via the WCF RIA Services.

There's also  the Prism MVVM model you can develop on top of.

However, I'd double check with the client as to what they are expecting.

Telerik also do a set of Silverlight controls.

Answer (score 0):

If the project time permits, go for Silverlight. Also, if needed, it's possible to create a desktop version (WPF) out of the Silverlight project.

Issues with Telerik control set(or any control set), if you need a control that doesn't exist in the current set, you'll have to either buy from Telerik, or create your own. In the latter case, the whole UI aesthetics might break because it's not easy to create a control matches the tool set.